# Calculations cannot be performed by passed value from two different subroutines to a new subroutine: Perl

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I used an anonymous hash to pass value from two different subroutines to a new subroutine. But, now I'm not able to perform calculations using the passed variables.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use DBI;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

print "Enter sequence";
my $seq = <STDIN>;
chomp $seq;
$len = length $seq;
my $f = nuc($seq);
perc({ len => $len });

sub nuc {
  my ($c) = @_;
  chomp $c;
  my $len = length $c;
  for (my $i = 0; $i< = $len; $i++) {
    my $seq2 = substr($c, $i, 1);
    $nuc=$nuc . $seq2;
    chomp $nuc; 
  }
  my $l = perc({nuc => $nuc});
} 

sub perc {
  my $params = shift;
  my $k = $params->{nuc};
  my $w = $params->{len};
  my $db = "hnf1a";
  my $user = "root";
  my $password = "";
  my $host = "localhost";
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password);
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mody where nm = ?');
  for (1..100) {
    $sth->execute(int(rand(10)));
  }
  chomp (my $input = $k);
  my @num = split /':'/, $input;
  for my $num(@num)  {
    say "rows matching input nuc <$num>:";
    $sth->execute($num);
    my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array;
    say "$count";
    $u += $count;
  }
} 
$h = $u / $w;
print $h;
```

I passed the variables : $nuc and $len to the last subroutine 'perc' by declaring an anonymous hash. 
When I use these variables to perform calculations I don't get a proper answer.
For the above division performed I got a statement as 'Illegal division'.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that it is readable. Thanks

Comment: @Mojo: I have cleaned up the formatting of your code to make it easier to follow. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are making two *separate* calls to `perc`, each with only one of the required values in the hash. You can't do that: the subroutine won't "remember" a value passed to it across separate calls unless you write the code to do that

You need to collect all the values and pass them in a *single* call to `perc`

Comment: But my variables are from different subroutines? How can I pass it in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

There are rather a lot of misunderstandings here. Let's go through your code.

```
use CGI;
```

Using CGI.pm is a bit dated, but it's not a terrible idea if you're writing a CGI program. But this isn't a CGI program, so this isn't necessary.

```
print "Enter sequence";
my $seq = <STDIN>;
chomp $seq;
$len = length $seq;
my $f = nuc($seq);
```

This looks OK. You prompt the user, get some input, remove the newline from the end of the input, get the length of the input and then pass your input into `nuc()`.

So, let's look at `nuc()` - which could probably have a better name!

```
sub nuc {
  my ($c) = @_;
  chomp $c;
  my $len = length $c;
  for (my $i = 0; $i< = $len; $i++) {
    my $seq2 = substr($c, $i, 1);
    $nuc=$nuc . $seq2;
    chomp $nuc; 
  }
  my $l = perc({nuc => $nuc});
}
```

You get the parameter that has been passed in and remove the newline from the end of it (which does nothing as this is `$seq` which has already had its newline removed). You then get the length of this string (again!)

Then it gets very strange. Firstly, there's a syntax error (`< =` should be `<=`). Then you use a C-style for loop together with `substr()` too... well, basically you just copy `$c` to `$nuc` in a really inefficient manner. So this subroutine could be written as:

```
sub nuc {
  my ($c) = @_;
  $nuc = $c;
  my $l = perc({ nuc => $nuc });
}
```

Oh, and I don't know why you `chomp($nuc)` each time round the loop.

Two more strange things. Firstly, you don't declare `$nuc` anywhere, and you have `use strict` in your code. Which means that this code doesn't even compile. (Please don't waste our time with code that doesn't compile!) And secondly, you don't explicitly return a value from `nuc()`, but you store the return value in `$f`. Because of the way Perl works, this subroutine will return the value in `$l`. But it's best to be explicit.

Then there's your `perc()` subroutine.

```
sub perc {
  my $params = shift;
  my $k = $params->{nuc};
  my $w = $params->{len};
  my $db = "hnf1a";
  my $user = "root";
  my $password = "";
  my $host = "localhost";
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password);
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mody where nm = ?');
  for (1..100) {
    $sth->execute(int(rand(10)));
  }
  chomp (my $input = $k);
  my @num = split /':'/, $input;
  for my $num(@num)  {
    say "rows matching input nuc <$num>:";
    $sth->execute($num);
    my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array;
    say "$count";
    $u += $count;
  }
}
```

You get the hash ref which is passed in an store that in `$params`. You then extract the `nuc` and `len` values from that hash and store them in variables called `$k` and `$w` (you really need to improve your variable and subroutine names!) But each call to `perc` only has one of those values set - so only one of your two variables get a value, the other will  be `undef`.

So then you connect to the database. And you run a select query a hundred times passing in random integers between 0 and 9. And ignore the value returned from the select statement. Which is bizarre and pointless.

Eventually, you start doing something with one of your input parameters, `$k` (the other, `$w`, is completely ignored). You copy it into another scalar variable before splitting it into an array. You then run the same SQL select statement once for each element in that array and add the number you get back to the running total in `$u`. And `$u` is another variable that you never declare, so (once again) this code doesn't compile.

Outside of your subroutines, you then do some simple maths with `$u` (an undeclared variable) and `$w` (a variable that was declared in a different scope) and store the result in `$h` (another undeclared variable).

I really don't understand what this code is supposed to do. And, to be honest, I don't think you do too. If you're at school, then you need to go back to your teacher and say that you have no idea what you are doing. If you're in a job, you need to tell your boss that you're not the right person for this task.

Either way, if you want to be a programmer, you need to go right back to the start and cover the very basics again.